# Displaying Result Of Query In DataGridView In Visual Studio 2012

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, datagridview

Ok first off, an important thing to note here is that I've been told to do this whole project without using code to write any of the SQL queries, TableAdapters, DataSources etc.. I've been told to use only Visual Studio's Wizards (not great I know) to generate all the queries and views. All the resources I've been able to find online just don't use the wizards, and are all done through code or older versions of Visual Studio.

Essentially the problem I'm having is that I have created a query on a table "CustomerOrders" which pulls in the FirstName and SecondName from the "Customers" table. All tables linked (database is built and working in access) Executing the Query Preview in the wizard performs as expected showing the correct and relevant columns.
[image: TableAdapter Query Configuration Wizard With Query]

Now the problem arises when I am trying to display this in a DataGridView.

When adding the DataGridView to my form I have to choose a binding source, so I choose the CustomerOrders table. This then displays all the columns in a DataGridView as expected. I then add the FillNames query to the form using the TableAdapterManager "Add Query" wizard.

This places a button on the form, which when pressed executes the query on the DataGridView as expected (it removes columns which I choose to hide in the query) but it does not display the columns from the Customers table - ie. FirstName and SecondName!

That's where the problem is, I can't pull in the names into this DataGridView from a different table other than the one defined in the Data Source (which I can only seem to add the one table to) I need to be able to add the columns from the Customers table into the DataGridView.

I hope this makes sense, and I know most of you will probably be able to do this no problem with code, but one of the requirements is that I do this using the built in Wizards..